# How can I decompile this executable?

Tags: music, decompile

I have a simple, freeware executable (48KB in size, that's about all the info I have on it).

I got it a few years back and can't remember where it's from. It's a worthless program to me now, but it has this really beastly .midi song (or some type of music file) playing in the background.

I have tried a few decompilers, such as Universal Extractor. I don't want source code, what I would love to get is the music file, because I have no idea what it is called. I don't have a microphone, or I would use a service such as SoundHound or something.

Would anyone happen to know of any decompilers that are capable of doing this?

Comment: *chuckle* would it happen to be a keygen? ;p

Comment: Haha of course not =p It's just an old file I would like to get of.. but that song is so catchy!

Comment: How do you expect us to know what "this" executable is, when you don't give specifics about it? You may be better off using a virtual sound card or similar solution to record the music.

Comment: All it does is play a song and display some swirling colors, there's not a whole lot to it. If there is at least a program that can analyze what the file was compiled with, so I can find a suitable decompiler, or something else, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: OH, DEMOSCENE... that might make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to open the executable and record the song directly with software such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/) and save it.

Comment: @ekaj you can set up Audacity to record "what you hear" without a mic. Here's a tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOaOeSzFO5U

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver trying to get this to work in Win7..

Comment: You will only be able to record "What u hear" if your soundcard supports this function. Otherwise, you can connect a cable between your headphone output to the microphone input, and set Audacity to record from the mic.

Answer (score 2):

A manual solution would be to open up the EXE in a [hex editor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and search for a MIDI header. [This page](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm) describes the MIDI format a little bit, including the header pattern. If/once you find the header, you could either manually track the chunks until you reach the end, or copy everything after that point into a separate .mid file and see if any MIDI-editing programs can open it and truncate the non-MIDI data.

Comment: IMO it's more likely to be a module format (mod/xm/s3m/it) than MIDI. e. g. http://www.fileformat.info/format/xm/corion.htm

Comment: Couldn't find the MIDI header, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If it's an Windows application, you could try with [ResHacker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/File-Editors/Resource-Hacker.shtml). It should work if the midi was set as a resource to a Vistual Studio project.

Comment: Does not work - "Unable to read resource section"

Comment: Perhaps it's packed with some sort of PE Protector software like Petite, Telock, WWPack, etc. In this case, it's harder to extract resources. You need to find an applications which can unprotect the file. I tried that ages ago, I have no clue what software to use, check with Google. Also, it might not be a Windows application in which case, ResHacker won't be of help.

Comment: It's an .exe, so it is a Win app.. forgot to specify OS in question..